# Search suggestion should not throw away other options from the search request

Tags: bug, search

Current implementation of "Did you mean" in search page works wrong! For instance: I try a search "[user:me incorrekt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20incorrekt)". In the result I see the following:

> [image: suggestion]

Clicking on suggested string completely throws away "user:me" option:

> [image: no user]

Such behaviour is weird, cause I need to type "user:me" again instead of only clicking on suggested link, which I think is main purpose of "did you mean" mechanism.

Comment: Ha-ha. This bug is not reproducible for me [anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+incorrekt).